# How to get field value from relations model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I need to get the value of the foreignkey field not as an id but as a value of one of the fields of the linked model.

**models.py**

```
class RfiParticipation(models.Model):
    ...
    vendor = models.ForeignKey('Vendors', models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='to_vendor')
    m = models.ForeignKey('Modules', models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='to_modules')
    ...

class Modules(models.Model):
    MODULES_NAME = (....
                    )
    mid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    module_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=MODULES_NAME, unique=True)
```

**serializer.py**

```
class VendorsManagementListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    company_information = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    vendor_modules = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Vendors
        fields = ('vendor_name',
                  ...
                  'company_information',
                  'vendor_modules',)


    def get_vendor_modules(self, obj):
        r = RfiParticipation.objects.filter(vendor=obj).order_by('rfi').values('m', 'rfi')
        return r
```

Now this request `r = RfiParticipation.objects.filter(vendor=obj).order_by('rfi').values('m', 'rfi')` returns to me:

```
 "vendor_modules": [

            {
                "m": 2,
                "rfi": "20R1"
            },
            {
                "m": 3,
                "rfi": "20R1"
            },
            {
                "m": 4,
                "rfi": "20R1"
            }
        ]
```

How I can make `m: module_name`  instead of `m: 2`? Where `module_name` is the field from Modules model. 
I try `.values('m.module_name', 'rfi')` but got

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'm.module_name' into field. Choices are: active, id, m, m_id, rfi, rfi_id, timestamp, user_id, vendor, vendor_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`SlugRelatedField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield) here. For example:

```
class RFISerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    to_modules = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
        slug_field='module_name'
    ) # using to_modules as it was used as related field

    class Meta:
        model = RfiParticipation
        fields = ['rfi', 'to_modules']


class VendorsManagementListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    vendor_modules = RFISerializer(source='m')

    class Meta:
        model = Vendors
        fields = ('vendor_name',
                  ...
                  'vendor_modules',)
```

Comment: I got error `AttributeError: 'Vendors' object has no attribute 'to_modules'
`. That's one of the reasons why I use SerializerMethodField

Comment: I found the solution ` m__module_name` is works as I expected

Answer (score 0):

Nice decision )

```
r = RfiParticipation.objects.filter(vendor=obj).order_by('rfi').values(module=F('m__module_name'), round=F('rfi'))
```